# Find intensity between two points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

would you give some hint how should I calculate intensity summation between two declare point in gray scale image?
any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: simply difference between pixel values of two points. [startpoint-endpoint] is this what exactly you want?

Comment: no, summation of points intensity between two points in a straight line.

Comment: You probably want to use something like [`improfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/improfile.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've used this method for point1 and point2:

```
x=[p1(1),p2(1)];y=[p1(2),p2(2)];
X=x(1):x(2);
Y=interp1(x,y,X);
Y=round(Y);
```

now I have positions of points so

```
I=0;
for i=1:length(X)
    I=I+Userimage(Y(i),X(i));
end
```